# How do you get all list information from Django view in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, django-models

I am trying to make a small web app using django and javascript however I have ran into a problem.

In my model I have an entity name "entry" which has attributes id, name, location_lat and location_lon all as char arrays. I pass entrys associated to a certain sport to a "map.html" file using the following code:

```
def sportpage(request,sportname):
t = get_template('map.html')
try:
    entry_list = Feature.objects.filter(sport=sportname)
except BaseException:
    raise Http404
sport_list = Sport.objects.all().order_by('name')
context = RequestContext(request,{'sport_list':sport_list,'entry_list':entry_list, 'page_title':sportname})
return HttpResponse(t.render(context))
```

and in the JavaScript file I attempt to read "entry_list" in using:

```
var data = "{{entry_list|safe}}";
```

However the data only contains a list of the entry names but not the location_lat or location_lon attributes. How would I gain access to these?

Thank you very much for any help